# C# Login Automation of Windows (XP, Vista, Etc..)

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-xp, authentication

I have an authentication key (USB dongle) that I would like to use in place of logging into windows. The dongle is not just a simple thumb-drive it is a specialized dongle made for software authentication.

I've seen tutorials on how to do this with Phidgets RFID kit, however I can't seem to find that tutorial anywhere now.

Basically I need something that looks for this key on start up. I already have the code to look for the key, I just need to be able to actually tell the system log in.

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you'd want to be writing something like this in C#, but the basics of how to customize the logon experience is outlined [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx).  Note that the mechanism changed between XP and Vista, so you'd probably need to write two different components if you wanted to support both.